# Correct syntax for setting object's property to return value of an object-function?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and was going through an example here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

```
function personFullName() {  
    return this.first + ' ' + this.last;  
}  
function personFullNameReversed() {  
    return this.last + ', ' + this.first;  
}  
function Person(first, last) {  
    this.first = first;  
    this.last = last;  
    this.fullName = personFullName;  
    this.fullNameReversed = personFullNameReversed;  
}  
var x = new Person('mickey', 'mouse');
document.write(x.fullName());
```

Why are the lines of code

```
    this.fullName = personFullName;  
    this.fullNameReversed = personFullNameReversed;
```

instead of

```
    this.fullName = personFullName();  
    this.fullNameReversed = personFullNameReversed();
```

I thought we're setting `this.fullName` based on the return value of `personFullName()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is making the "fullName" and "fullNameReversed" properties be **functions**, not simple properties.

Thus when you want the full name you'd write `x.fullName();`

Functions are objects in JavaScript and can be the value of variables and properties.  This is a feature that makes JavaScript surprisingly powerful.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.fullName = personFullName;
```

Creates a method called `fullName`, and assigns it the **function** declared as `personFullName`

If you were to do

```
this.fullName = personFullName();
```

that would create an object property called `fullName` that held the value that `personFullName()` produced at that particular moment when invoked.

Answer (score 1):

`personFullName` returns the function itself (like a pointer).

`personFullName()` returns the results of the function.

This allows the `Person` object to have a method that returns the full name, as opposed to a  property. If I use this object like `x.first = newVal`, the `fullName` method re-calculates the full name.

If it were a property, I would have to use it like ''x.first = newVal; x.fullName = newFullName;'.

Hope this helps.